# Every installation in my node v18.13.0 always shows 'Primordial not defined" am using windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

C:\node_modules>npm install -g npm
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Eduur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "npm"
npm ERR! node v18.13.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.3

npm ERR! primordials is not defined
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\node_modules\npm-debug.log

I have searched everywhere still can't find the problem to this error.

Comment: Please I need a help seriously

Comment: Try `npm cache clean --force` to remove any cached packages and re-install them. It seems the issue is with Node.js version 18.13.0. The library you're using might not be compatible. You can also try to downgrade Node.js to a version compatible with the packages or libraries you are using.

Comment: It would also be helpful to see your `package.json`.